# DynamoDB - Query instead of Scan - how to achive with random generated key

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

**Setup**

I have the following table in java and DynamoDB (DynamoDB Mapper) annotations:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName="myentity")
public class MyEntity {
@DynamoDBHashKey
@DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
private String id;

@DynamoDBIndexHashKey()
//@DynamoDBIndexRangeKey
private String userId;

private Date eventDate;
```

The `id` is randomly generated when saved and the same `userId` can occur for multiple entities.

The tables where defined via Web GUI like this:
Primary partition key:  id (String)
Primary sort key:   userId (String)

**Issue**

I would like to have all the entities for one userId with a query instead of a scan.

Query - does not work like this:

```
public List<MyEntity> findByUserIdQuery(String userId) {
    Map<String, AttributeValue> eav = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
    eav.put(":val1", new AttributeValue().withS(userId));

    DynamoDBQueryExpression<MyEntity> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<MyEntity>()
        .withKeyConditionExpression("userId = :val1").withExpressionAttributeValues(eav);

    List<MyEntity> list = mapper.query(MyEntity.class, queryExpression);
```

of course I get:

```
com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: Query condition missed key schema element: id (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: 123) at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1305)
```

because I don't know the generated id when I want to read data.

**Workaround**

Instead I use:

```
public List<MyEntity> findByOwner(String userId){

    Map<String, AttributeValue> eav = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
    eav.put(":val1", new AttributeValue().withS(userId));

    DynamoDBScanExpression scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression()
        .withFilterExpression("userId = :val1").withExpressionAttributeValues(eav);

    List<MyEntity> list = mapper.scan(MyEntity.class, scanExpression);
```

**Possible solutions**

The issue is that I never know the randomly generated key for the elements I have. When I want to read I only know the userId and I want to have all entities for them.

I watched the examples here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.QueryScanExample.html
...but they know always the key for what they are searching. They are using a combinded key like this:

```
String partitionKey = forumName + "#" + threadSubject;*
eav.put(":val1", new AttributeValue().withS(partitionKey))
Map<String, AttributeValue> eav = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
DynamoDBQueryExpression<Reply> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<Reply>()
            .withKeyConditionExpression("Id = :val1 and ReplyDateTime > :val2").withExpressionAttributeValues(eav);
```

**Question**

- Is there something like a wildcard for this combinded partition key that I could use? (Something like: "* # myGreatUser")
- Other suggestions for db setup and other annotations as key element?
- Maybe an Index where I could use query instead of scan?
- Maybe somebody has a working example for this kind of use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to switch your partition key and sort key around.

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName="myentity")
public class MyEntity {

@DynamoDBRangeKey
@DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
private String id;

@DynamoDBHashKey
private String userId;

private Date eventDate;
```

And then query using

```
public List<MyEntity> findByUserIdQuery(String userId) {
    Map<String, AttributeValue> eav = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
    eav.put(":val1", new AttributeValue().withS(userId));

DynamoDBQueryExpression<MyEntity> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<MyEntity>()
    .withKeyConditionExpression("userId = :val1").withExpressionAttributeValues(eav);

List<MyEntity> list = mapper.query(MyEntity.class, queryExpression);
```

By the way, you mentioned that you thought your sort key was userId, but in the example supplied you have a primary hash key of id and a global secondary index hash key of userid. There is no sort key.

Comment: Thanks it helped. So easy. When I thought of the web gui `Primary partition key` or `DynamoDBHashKey`, I always had uniqueness in my mind. Even better I could discard the auto generated `id` and took the `eventDate` instead. For the sort key: In the web gui if you create a table there is a checkbox with "Add sort key" direct after the "partition key".